# Am not able to send Bulk sms using the code below

Tags: php, mysql, kannel

I am a newbie in PHP and MySQL i have written the code below to enable sending of bulk sms with the phone number being picked for a database with the phone number being in different tables where they are selected using a form but am not able to send the bulk sms's any help will be highly appreciated.

```
     if (!$con)
     {
     die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }

       mysql_select_db("demo_forum", $con);

       if($result = mysql_query("SELECT phn_number FROM gen");
  ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

       elseif ($result = mysql_query("SELECT phn_number FROM tec"); 
  ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

  elseif ($result = mysql_query("SELECT phn_number FROM news"); 
    ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

   elseif ($result = mysql_query("SELECT phn_number FROM pol");
    ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

   else ($result = mysql_query("SELECT phn_number FROM pol, gen, news, tec"); 
    ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

     function sendSmsMessage($phn_number, $message)
      {
     $ch= curl_init();curl_setopt($ch, "http://$gw_host/process_sm/sendsms.php?to=$phn_numbermessage=.urlencode($message");
      curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);

       }
```

Comment: I really do not get the purpose of that whole query `if/elseif/else` tree, what do you actually want to achieve with that? Also you never call the `sendSmsMessage()` function anywhere in the code, and it appears to be completely unrelated to the database code.

Comment: You're not able to send SMS. Why? what does it happen? any error showing? any strange behavior? the script executes completely with no output? "IT DOES NOT WORK" can't be helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $ch= curl_init();curl_setopt($ch, "http://$gw_host/process_sm/sendsms.php?to=$phn_numbermessage=.urlencode($message");
```

lacks the [ampersand (&)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) seperating the different fields in your query string and your string contains the literal `.urlencode($message` due to your incorrect placement of the second **"**

try

```
 $ch= curl_init();curl_setopt($ch, "http://$gw_host/process_sm/sendsms.php?to=$phn_number&message=" . urlencode($message));
```

Comment: this solved it and am able to send the sms now thank you so much